# XSLT transformation of soap

Tags: xslt, soap, transformation

I have this xml file

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://testwork/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>?</arg0>
      </tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to extract body using xslt transformation, my xsl is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But during the transformation there appears error

```
Unable to perform XSL transformation on your XML file. null
```

What is wrong with my xsl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSL is missing the namespaces that are in your XML. Without it, your XSL can't find your elements in the XML because it would be looking in the wrong namespace for it.

So add

```
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:tes="http://testwork/"
```

To your XSL and it should transform without issue.